# When can bokashi be considered "compost"?

Tags: compost

Every now and then I come across an answer here that suggests "adding a bit of compost" to a plant - eg. for example to help it bounce back from an injury.

I'm composting using a bokashi bin in my kitchen which, when full, has its contents buried in a hole in the backyard.

Is this considered compost at the stage of burying? Or should it be left in the ground and then dug up after a certain time (how long?) before it could be safely added to a plant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bokashi is food that has been pickled by the use of Effective Microrganisms in an anaerobic process.  This purportedly makes it unattractive to animals when buried ( though I've had animals dig up my bokashi ).  When mixed in with a normal compost pile, or buried in the ground, it undergoes normal decomposition much faster than if just buried/composted fresh, taking a few weeks rather than months.

I'd dig it up once it looks like regular compost if you want to redistribute it in your garden.  But I regularly dig in my Bokashi at the bottom of a hole, add a soil layer on top of the Bokashi, and then plant something on top of that, and I've had great results.  I grew my corn, zucchinis, and now my garlic that way.

Comment: Thanks Graham! A few weeks sounds good before checking it. I like the idea of digging it in at the bottom too